# Dynamic SQL for CASE Statements to remove hardcode

Tags: sql, loops, dynamic-sql

I've a Dynamic SQL that is required to be optimized. I need to make CASE Expression Dynamic. I've a list of ATTRIBUTE_LIST & SCENARIO_LIST, that are provided below. I wrote a Function to get them Dynamically. How can I replace Three CASE Expression and make it Dynamic? I'm trying to avoid hard coding.

```
SET @ATTRIBUTE_LIST = 'symbol_type, currency, performing_status' -- INPUTS
SET @SCENARIO_LIST = 'historicalsimulation_1day_end_10dec2013, historicalsimulation_1day_end_11dec2013'

SELECT CASE
           WHEN (GROUPING(Scenario_Name) = 1) THEN ''ALL''
           WHEN (Scenario_Name = ''[BaseCase]'') THEN ''BaseCase''
           ELSE ISNULL(Scenario_Name, '''')
       END AS Scenario_Name,
       CASE
           WHEN (GROUPING(Symbol_Type) = 1) THEN ''ALL''
           ELSE ISNULL(Symbol_Type, '''')
       END AS Symbol_Type,
       CASE
           WHEN (GROUPING(Currency) = 1) THEN ''ALL''
           ELSE ISNULL(Currency, '''')
       END AS Currency,
       CASE
           WHEN (GROUPING(Performing_Status) = 1) THEN ''ALL''
           ELSE ISNULL(Performing_Status, '''') \
       END AS Performing_Status,
       SUM(Value) AS ScenarioValue
FROM [20151005_171003_UserName_NT-22_Analysis_Tue] o
     LEFT JOIN [20151005_171003_UserName_NT-22_Analysis_Tue_Position_Data] pld 
          ON o.Position_Unique_Identifier=pld.Position_Unique_Identifier
GROUP BY ' + @ATTRIBUTE_LIST + ' WITH CUBE) AS DATA 
   PIVOT ( Sum(scenariovalue)
             FOR scenario_name IN (' + @SCENARIO_LIST + ')'
```

Comment: Please, don't tag products not involved. (MySQL and MS SQL Server...)

Comment: That's case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: Okay. I'm new to SQL. So what's the answer ?

Comment: Modified as per your comment. Now let me know if you can optimize the Case "Expression". Thanks.

Comment: provide some data to understand what's going on. what's the input? what's the expected output? what's the actual output in terms of produced sql code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.   "Make it dynamic" is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: Paola - SET @ATTRIBUTE_LIST = 'symbol_type, currency, performing_status' is the input of the CASE Expression. So number of elements in the list could be n number. We should use above list as input data.

Comment: Tab - Thanks. This is what I'm looking for. below CASE need to be optimized and rather than writing same Type of Case over and over we need to make it Dynamic.Where Symbol_Type is one input. Let me know if it's still not clear to you. - Thanks. CASE 
                    WHEN (GROUPING(Symbol_Type) = 1) 
                        THEN ''ALL''                      
                    ELSE ISNULL(Symbol_Type, '''')               
                        END AS Symbol_Type,

Comment: What's going on Boys ? Are we clear about Question and Formatting now ? Can we get any real solution ?

Comment: This isn't really a SQL question per se. Whatever function/method you used for the other lists is probably the approach you ought to take for whatever you're trying to accomplish here. I'm not sure if translation is an issue but your attitude is coming off as very pushy and rude.

Comment: Well.. Likewise shawnt. That was a rude answer. I was looking help just like another developer who works under pressure and deadline. This is an open forum. If you think you can't answer no one is pushing you. Sorry for the miscommunication and my apology!

Comment: Don't mistake us for being a forum, We are not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Comment: BTW, Thanks to shawnt00 for quick and exact solution I was looking for. Pretty helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using SQL Server. Here's a brute-force way of looping over your attributes and building a series of `case` expressions:

```
declare @cases nvarchar(max) = '';

declare @l varchar(max) = @ATTRIBUTE_LIST + ',';
declare @ofs int = 0;
declare @pos int = charindex(',', @l, @ofs + 1);

while @pos > 0
begin
    if @cases <> '' set @cases = @cases + ',';
    set @cases = @cases +
            replace('
       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(<COL>) = 1) THEN ''ALL''
           ELSE ISNULL(<COL>, '''')
       END AS <COL>',
           '<COL>', substring(@l, @ofs + 1, @pos - @ofs - 1)
    ); 
    set @ofs = @pos;
    set @pos = charindex(',', @l, @ofs + 1);
end
select @cases;
```